# How to dispatch blocks with many arguments on a different thread synchronously?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, parse-platform, ios9

I need to upload some data to server. Just before doing so, I fetch an entity that this data should be bounded to(simple relationship). If there is no such entity, I want to create it then and continue uploading process. The problem, though, is that if there are too many requests, all requests will end up faster than creation of the entity, thus many entities will be created. The solution is to dispatch the block of code synchronously, but on a different thread. How do I do this?

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0), ^{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FileOwner"];
    [query whereKey:@"identifier" equalTo:@"ABCDEFG"];
    PFObject *fileOwner = [query getFirstObject];
    if(fileOwner){
         [self continueUploadingData:data completionHandler:completionBlock];
    }
    else{
         PFObject *newFileOwner = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"FileOwner"];
         newPhotoOwner[@"identifier"] = @"ABCDEFG";
         [newPhotoOwner saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
              if(succeeded)[self continueUploadingData:data completionHandler:completionBlock];
         }];
    }
});
```

This works, but obviously blocks the main thread. I can't use `detachSelector: toTarget: withObject:` because I have more than one argument.

Comment: Why is the solution to perform the operation synchronously?  I have an answer in mind for an asynchronous approach but I know you want a synchronous solution. Also, is `photoOwner` being defined outside of the block or is it a typo?

Comment: @WilliamSmith. Well, I am interested in solution. Not in solution itself. Synchronous operation is just my first thought, but it is not a rule. So I am glad to see what you suggest. And yes, that was "midnight" typo. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general purpose advice that will help here is to build the atomic functions with methods that take completion blocks (like parse's, maybe like your `continueUploading` method).

In this case, we need a function that will look for an object, return it if it's found, or create and return it if it's not found, all asynch...

```
- (void)findOrCreateFileOwnerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier completion:(void (^)(PFObject *, NSError *))completion {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FileOwner"];
    [query whereKey:@"identifier" equalTo:identifier];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (object) {
            return completion(object, nil);
        } else {
            PFObject *newFileOwner = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"FileOwner"];
            newFileOwner[@"identifier"] = identifier;
            [newFileOwner saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
        }
    }];
}
```

Now you can say...

```
[self findOrCreateFileOwnerWithIdentifier:@"ABCDEFG" completion:^(PFObject *fileOwner, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self continueUploadingData:data completionHandler:completionBlock];
    } else {
        // handle error... probably pass it to completionBlock
        // not shown because the OP code doesn't show how the block is declared
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I call `findOrCreateFileOwnerWithIdentifier` in a `for` loop. Wouldn't this approach lead to the same problem of many entities or  am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything.  On the client, the way to sequentialize operations is by starting the subsequent operations in the completion block.  For arbitrarily many, parameterize them with an array, and then have the calling method call itself recursively from the completion block (advancing an index into the array or truncating it).  A better answer when using parse is to move whatever you can to cloud code (a) promises really cleanup the concurrency code (b) less wasted resources moving intermediate results to the client.